# (Multiple Integral) The mass of a bullet shape, given its density and equation for the curved top

Tags: multiple-integral

I'm trying to calculate the mass of a bullet-shaped object; a cylinder and a curved top, where only the density and equation for the round top is known.

bullet-shaped object is formed from a cylinder with a curved top. A
cylinder that has radius a is situated with its base on the (x, y)-plane with
the origin located at the centre of the base. The curved top of the bullet is

The cylinder is situated with its base on the $(x, y)$-plane with the origin located at the centre of the base.

The radius of the cylinder is equal to $a$.

The curved top is given by the formula: $$z = 4a-\frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}{a}$$

Density is given by $$D \cdot \left(\frac{\rho^2}{a^2}+1 \right)$$
where $a$ and $D$ are constants.

Attempt:

I'm sure it's a matter of triple integration:

$$ \text {Mass } = \int \delta V = \int f(\rho,\phi,z) ~\rho ~\delta z ~\delta \phi ~\delta \rho$$
$$= \int D \cdot \left(\frac {\rho^3}{a^2} + \rho \right) ~\delta z ~\delta \rho $$

I think the scalar field $f$ is
independent of the azimuthal angle $\phi$ so we instead have:

$$\int\delta V = 2\pi \int_0^h D \cdot \left(\frac{\rho^3}{a^2}+\rho \right) ~\delta z ~ \delta\rho$$

Now, I have the density, and I have the equation for the curved top. How do I go about calculating the density of both the cylinder and the curved top?

I'd appreciate if, someone does take a shot at shedding some light on the problem, if they used similar notation.

Comment: Also, is $\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ i.e is $\rho$ the radius in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: (I can't get mathjax to work in comments). the fractions are being taken away from 4a.

And yes, I'm using cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: I understand you are using cylindrical coordinates in your solution but it is important to understand what $\rho$ means in the given density $D \cdot \left(\frac{\rho^2}{a^2}+1 \right)$. It is likely that $\rho$ is the radius in cylindrical coordinates but it should be stated otherwise $\rho$ could mean $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ which is radial distance from origin (spherical coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notations are not very clear. If $~\rho~$ is the radial distance from z-axis to a point, parallel to xy-plane, then $~\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, x = \rho \cos\phi, y = \rho \sin\phi$

The curved top is $~ \displaystyle z = 4a-\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{a} = 4a - \frac{\rho^2 \cos 2\phi}{a}~$. As it sits on top of the cylinder of radius $a$ with base of the cylinder in xy-plane i.e. $z = 0$, the triple integral for the mass of the object can be written as,

$$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a \int_0^{(4a^2 - \rho^2 \cos 2\phi) /a} D \cdot \left(\rho + \frac{\rho^3}{a^2}\right) ~ dz ~ d\rho ~ d\phi$$

Comment: That's the integral for the entire bullet-shaped object, and not just the curved top?

Comment: Yes for the entire object. The lower limit of $z$ is $0$ and that is where the base of the object is. It is a circular base and the height at a given radius and polar angle is from the equation of the curved top.

Comment: Thank you. What threw me off was the equation for the curved top; how to start tackling the problem, not being able to put the pieces together. This is much appreciated.